# Make it so that the console will display whatever the user IS typing at the bottom?

Tags: java

I have a program that prints output to the command prompt but suppose this happens.

> while (true) { System.out.println("Something"); }

And then in another thread the program will get input from the user.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
try { input = reader.readLine(); } catch ( Exception e ) { /* Do Nothing */ }
```

Now, there are two threads being executed at the same time, And if I try to type *Hello World*, this will happen;

```
Something
Something
Something
Something
HSomething
elloSomething
Something W
Something orl
Something d
Something
```

Is there a way so that whatever the user is typing remains at the bottom, I want it to be like this;

```
Something
Something
Something
Something
Something
Something
Something
Hello World
Something
```

P.S: The reader can still tell which the user typed and what the program printed. But the user will find it very hard to tell which is which.
P.P.S: Suppose that it's like this;

```
Something
Something
Hello World
Something
```

Because the program printed right after the user pressed Enter; I hope you know what i want.

Comment: You could have a sort of timer, say counting 3 seconds: at every user key stroke you restart it and if it does reach the 3 seconds start writing to the console again.

Comment: good point assylias problem is how to tell the program to stop execution or sleep while user is typing?

Answer (score 0):

You do not "have a program that prints output to the command prompt".

You have a program that writes to the console.

The purpose of a console is to give you a very easy way of emitting a sequential (teletype-style) stream of text.

For anything more complicated than that, your program must *not* write to a console, it must use a GUI.

Google AWT and JavaFX to get started.

<sub>Note: back in the days when the only thing that existed was text terminals, and yet the needs of the computing industry had already grown to demand more fancy ways of emitting text than what teletype had to offer, various hacky wacky quirky clanky ways were invented to position the cursor at specific places on the screen, and even to specify the color of the text.  They mostly worked by emitting special sequences of control characters. On most systems today, the console window that you get by default does not support any such control characters.  But even if it did, you explicitly asked for the help of a "professional java programmer", (so presumably you do not care for the opinion of a hacker?) and a professional is obliged to advice you to stay clear from antiquated, overly complex and cryptic, and ultimately hacky ways of doing things.</sub>

Comment: yeah but still, isn't writing and printing output the same thing? Also don't you have to be a professional to be a hacker? But good point i'll go ahead and learn the java.awt library

Comment: 1. yes, they are the same thing, you focused on the wrong word. 2. no, you are unlikely to be a professional if you are a hacker, and unlikely to be a hacker if you are a professional.